# Face detection using opencv

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I am using haarcascade_frontalface_default cascade for face detection using Viola Jones Object Detector.
Can anyone suggest any other method/xml file to increase the range (unto 20ft) (maximum distance from the camera at which a user can be detectted) of face detection for the same camera

Answer (score 1):

`1.` You should try `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml`.

`2.` Depending on your application needs, you could try to filte the detection results w.r.t. the scale of the corresponding bounding boxes, in order to decrease the false positive rate of your system.